# Ensure variable declaration only happen at beginning of scope block

Tags: c, gcc, scope, variable-declaration

We recently lost our ability to test codes on C compilers which require variable declaration to happen at the beginning of a scope block.

It didn't take long before the source code started to be invaded by declarations anywhere in any block. These coding-style differences remained unnoticed for a while, because none of our warnings could caught them. But they are pretty bad for our portability objectives.

There is an ongoing effort to restore our capability to make continuous tests on C compilers with this restriction. But in parallel, I try to find some gcc warning-flag combination which could help detect it.

`-std=c90` or `-pedantic` would detect that situation, but they would also generate tons of other unwanted warnings. For example, I want to authorize `//` comment style, or comma at end of enumerator list, or `(...)` variadic macros or `long long` types.
Sometimes there is a way to turn some specific warning off (`-Wno-long-long` or `-Wno-variadic-macros`), and sometimes I can't find any (`//` comment style).

It sounds silly to enable a pack of warnings and disable most of them just to keep the relevant one. But if that's the only possibility, I'm fine with it.

Comment: Mixing declarations and statements is valid C, so any compliant compiler shall accept such code. As it also is just a matter of style and not more error-prone than dclarations at the start of a block it would be a surprise a compiler provides such an option. After all, a compiler is no style-checker.

Comment: `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` is the guy you want.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: Did I miss the question in that rant? It just looks like some personal statement.

Comment: @Olaf: Technically there's no question, but "I try to find some gcc warning-flag combination which could help detect it" comes close enough for jazz, I think.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: I still don't think this should be part of the compiler. Because the warning renders perfectly valid code invalid at worst (if `-Werror`) just to enforce an ancient coding style. Sometimes such mixed declarations are very useful and increase readability.

Comment: @Olaf: Sure, but it is part of the compiler, for gcc at least. It's far from inconceivable that people still need stuff to compile on pre-C99 compilers, although admittedly allowing all the other stuff kind of defeats the purpose there. But it is a valid and on-topic question, even if it's odd to want such a thing.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: It would be valid if it did ask a clear question (and could be much shorter), but it is badly researched, even more as the option is quite self-explanatory. Anyway, instead of forbidding this feature, moving away from pre-C99 and closer to C11 with good traning for the programmers would pay off much more. Anyway, agreed, this is an opinion, how well founded it might be.

Comment: why don't upgrade the compilers if they don't support mixed declarations?

Comment: Thanks @PaulGriffiths, this is exactly the option wanted, and it works as expected. If you want to make it an answer, I will vote for and select it.

Comment: Just my experience,, I've dealt with some Wind River compilers (can't remember versions it was a couple years ago) that were _very_ strict. They would throw errors if all the declarations weren't at the beginning of functions, would throw errors for the `//` comments, and strangest of all, they would throw warnings if the last line of each file didn't end with a newline. I went through dozens of files adding newlines just to suppress those warnings. Anyway, point being that some of these things are still strictly enforced in the wild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-Wdeclaration-after-statement` is the gcc option you want. From the manual page:

> Warn when a declaration is found after a statement in a block. This
>   construct, known from C++, was introduced with ISO C99 and is by
>   default allowed in GCC.  It is not supported by ISO C90 and was not
>   supported by GCC versions before GCC 3.0.